# Is it a bad idea to maintain a separate login sessions in MySQL and Code Behind?

Tags: c#, mysql, session, triggers, rdbms

I have an application with C# code behind, which maintains a session state and has a value set for timeout and some redirect on session timeout logic in place.

Additionally, I have a MySQL requirement in which I am going to write triggers to store information about which logged in users last modified each table.

So, it seems that the easiest way to provide the triggers with a value for who is logged into the application, would be to copy the C# session to a MySQL session variable. This variable might not expire at the same time as the C# session does, but it will be reset each time a new person logs in.

Do you think there is another/better solution?

Comment: What would you want to do when a logged in user logs out, as far as records that they are recorded as the last logged in user for? For example, user A modifies at a record, then user B modifies at the same record. User B now logs out. Do you want to now report no logged in user as the last to modify it, or do you want to display user A as the last logged in user to modify it?

Comment: good question, in my case I was thinking more of a logging situation. So I would have user a at 2pm performed an update, user b at 2:15pm performed an update

Answer (score -1):

When any user logged in then add informations of that user in your sql table.

Comment: I suspect he down voted you because you did not answer the question. Im not looking for 'last user logged in'. I m looking for 'current user logged in', and if nobody is logged in, then I will mark it as system user. Please read my posting for the rest of the question, and if you update your answer for the question, I will upvote you so you will end up breaking even :) Cheers